# Optimizing snap SVG animation with collision detection

Tags: javascript, animation, collision, svg

I have a snap SVG animation which animates a bunch of circles, and draws a line between them if they are within a certain proximity of each other. However, I realize that there is a lot of optimizing I can do, but I'm not exactly sure how to do it. I feel like it would be useful to

1. have a good example of proximity detection in snap
2. have some more information on optimizing animations in snap SVG. It hasn't been easy to find.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/heaversm/sbj4W/1/) is a working example of the animation:

and here are the things I believe can be optimized:

---

Each circle calls its own animation function - the circles have all been added to a group, and I'm guessing there is a way to apply random motion to all members of a group that is more performant than call a function for each and every element within the group.

```
for (var i=0; i<this.drawingConfig.circles.amount;i++){
  ...
  this.animateSingle(circleShape);
}
```

---

The proximity function is awkward - for each circle, for each update cycle, I have to loop through an array of all the other circles and find out if the X and Y coordinates are close enough to draw a line to. Plus, that means you're getting duplicate lines, because each circle will draw a line to its neighbors, instead of having a single shared line between the two.

```
for (var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){
  var nextCircle = circles[i].node;
  var nextCircleX = nextCircle.cx.baseVal.value;
  var distance = Math.abs(nextCircleX-thisCircleX);
  var proximity = mainModule.drawingConfig.circles.proximity;
  if (distance < proximity){

    var nextCircleY = nextCircle.cy.baseVal.value;
    var thisCircleY = shape.node.cy.baseVal.value;
    var distanceY = Math.abs(nextCircleY - thisCircleY);
    if (distanceY < proximity){

      var line = mainModule.s.line(thisCircleX, thisCircleY, nextCircleX, nextCircleY).attr({stroke: '#a6a8ab', strokeWidth: '1px'});
      mainModule.drawingConfig.circles.circleGroup.add(line);
    }
  }
}
```

---

Correspondingly, I each circle's animation function clears all the lines on the screen. Ideally all the circles would be sharing one update function, and in that function, you'd clear the lines.

```
Snap.animate(startX, animX, function (val) {

  var lines = Snap.selectAll('line');
  lines.remove();

  ...

}, mainModule.drawingConfig.circles.animTime);
```

Right now, I can tell the renderer can't keep up with all of the various animations / loops. Any help optimizing the above things (or anything else you can see that I'm doing weird, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Am now running everything in a single loop - not using snap's animation function at all;
[check this](http://jsfiddle.net/heaversm/fJ6fj/).